# Vue/Nuxt page transition leave not working

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js, vue-router, vue-transitions

so I tried to do page transitions on css but the `leave` transition didn't work, so I tried to do it with `JS Hooks`, but leave animations still doesn't work. I tried commenting on every step and I discovered that `leave` is not even getting called.

### Script:

```js
methods: {
    beforeEnter: function (el) {
      console.log("Before Enter")
      // ...
    },
    enter: function (el, done) {
      console.log("Entered")
      // ...
    },
    leave: function (el, done) {
      console.log("Leave")
      // ...
    }
  }
```

### Template:

```html
<div id="app">
  <nav-bar />
  <transition
    mode="out-in"
    @before-enter="beforeEnter"
    @enter="enter"
    @leave="leave"
  >
    <nuxt />
  </transition>
</div>
```

[image: Screenshot of website behavior]

I have read the [documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/transitions-enterleave.html#explicit-transition-durations) for the transitions and I have even copied their code and pasted it as it is but still seems to be of no difference. I used `yarn create nuxt-app` so you would assume I'm on the most stable update

```
nuxt: 2.15.8

node: 14.18.1

ubuntu: 18.04.6 LTS
```

Comment: Hi, did my answer helped somehow?

Comment: @kissu wooh I saw your message but forgot to reply, when you answered at that point I thought Nuxtjs uses vue3 and since then I've lost hope of learning nuxtjs until nuxt3 becomes near stable to work with. your answer helped me because I think if you didn't tell me I would've took a long time to realize that nuxt uses vue2 lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation that you've linked is related to Vue3, and the API is a bit different there in comparison of Nuxt2 (using Vue2).
Here is the one you should [look at](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#CSS-Transitions).

This being by far the easiest to manage transitions

```html
<transition name="slide-fade">
  <p v-if="show">hello</p>
</transition>
```

```css
.slide-fade-enter-active {
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
.slide-fade-leave-active {
  transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(1.0, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0);
}
.slide-fade-enter, .slide-fade-leave-to
/* .slide-fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
  transform: translateX(10px);
  opacity: 0;
}
```